# React-native FlatList component is Not Working

Tags: react-native

Hello I am a beginner to react-native. I was practicing with a basic app which reads the input from the user and display it in the screen. I am trying to use the FlatList but it is not rendering. 
Here is my code

```js
    export default function App() {
      const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState(
        ""
      ); /* constant and method  with String*/

      const [enteredString, setEnteredString] = useState(
        []
      ); /* constant and method  with Array  */

      const enteredTextHandler = (enteredText) => {
        setEnteredText(enteredText);
      }; /* Set the entered text to the constant value*/

      const addTextHandler = () => {
        setEnteredString((currentString) => [
          ...currentString,
          { id: Math.random().toString(), value: enteredText },
       ]); /*  Add entered text to the array */
      };

      return (
        <View style={styles.mainView}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter te value"
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={enteredTextHandler}
              value={enteredText}
            />
            <Button title="Add" onPress={addTextHandler} style={styles.button} />
          </View>
          <FlatList
            data={enteredString}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={(itemData) => {
              console.log(itemData.item.value);
              <View style={styles.listStyle}>
                <Text>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
              </View>;
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you've reused the variable name `enteredText` in your `enteredTextHandler`. I think the way it's set up it'll always set enteredText to blank.

Try using a different name for the text argument:

```
const enteredTextHandler = newText => {
    setEnteredText(newText);
  }; /* Set the entered text to the constant value*/
```

Comment: I tried with your code but still it is not working. but the output is coming in the console

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
 <FlatList
    data={enteredString}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem={(itemData) => (
      <View style={styles.listStyle}>
        <Text>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
  />
```

I was written the syntax wrong. previously I used **(itemData) => {}** but the actual syntax is **(itemData) => ()** . Instead of parantesis I used curly braces that's why it was not displaying.

Comment: You can't get answer.  you just do not read the documentation . Strongly recommend firstable read documentation => https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist